# Understanding Principal Components Analyse (PCA) for Dimension Downscaling in EEG signals

Tags: python, signal-processing, pca

I have read dozens of scientific articles and wherever a large number of channels are used to read EEG signals, the Principal Components Analyze method is used to reduce the Dimension.

I have read the theory about Principal Components Analyze many times and think that understanding how it works, each component is a new coordinate system for the data.
I implemented this method in Python for my data but ended up with new EEG data that was modeled relative to new components (coordinates) but the data became larger since I used few components.

Therefore, why is this method considered to reduce the dimension, because we end up with even more data if we use several components?

I attached image for my 9 channels  and the result after PCA
[my data before and after PCA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8xh0.jpg)

I can not understand, PCA finally doesn't decrease the dimension of EEG data, where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Note that I am no expert as it comes to using PCA for EEG signals analysis.

PCA does decrease dimensions IF you choose to. Usually only first few components are important and you can discard all the others. How many - it depends on your needs.

PCA creates new, independent dimensions, with first being most important, "describing" as much of the data variance as it is possible for a single variable to describe. Second PCA dimension is second important and so on.

In your case it may be ok to keep only first 3-4 PCA components. But I am guessing. Best is to check this in some further step, for example checking "how many components can I remove before classification task accuracy drops" or something like that. You could also take a look at signals reconstructed using inverse PCA transform (available in sklearn)

Comment: Thank you, but finally, the size of the data will not decrease. in each component there will be exactly the same amount of data as it was before processing, is that right?
Or by reducing the dimensional, it is understood that the difference between the value between data will be small, they say they will be averaged due to the new coordinate axes, for example, was 11 and 1 (Axe - 0) after PCA it will be 6 and 4 (Axe -5)

Comment: If you by data mean number of data samples, then yes, the size will be the same. PCA will transform each of your sample to its representation in new (PCA) dimensions. What may decrease is number of dimensions (again, only if you choose to reduce number of dimensions)